# PrimeNG Calendar change date fomat ddMMyyyy to dd.mm.yy

Tags: angular, primeng, date-formatting, primeng-calendar

PrimeNG calendar exists on filter page. If the user writes date as *ddMMyyyy* format, the date should be converted to *dd.mm.yy* format and the date written on the calendar must be selected. How can do this on HTML page ?

```
   <p-calendar id="beginSystemCreated" formControlName="beginSystemCreated" [showIcon]="true" [locale]="tr_calendar_locale" 
dateFormat="dd.mm.yy" [maxDate]="invoiceSearchForm.controls['endSystemCreated'].value" (onInput)="DateValidator()"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: There is no *mask* property for `p-calendar` right now. Maybe you could add `placeholder="dd.mm.yy"` to tell the user what you expect ?

Comment: Bad tagging. Read the info about the tags. Do you use them all?